# Selenium- PY Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting an unnecessary error in the program I'm trying to write with selenium.I wonder what the solution is that the code fragment I gave below works and gives the last error after it runs.

```
  submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[2]/div/form/div/input")
submit.click()
```

[Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3w9N.png)

Comment: It would be better to provide the error message as text, rather than a linked image.

Also, without seeing the source data you're trying to parse, it'd be difficult to see what the error might be.

Comment: When I got into the for, the problem was solved. Thanks